# Select multiple rows for distinct column if column not null, otherwise select first row where column is null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an interesting query I need to execute. For Table A below, I want to select ALL non null **phoneNumber** for distinct **userId**, but if a non null **phoneNumber** value doesn't exist for distinct **userId** select **only one** null **phoneNumber** for distinct **userId**.

Table A

```
| id | userId | phoneNumber | emailAddress | 
 ------------------------------------------- 
| 1  |   1    | 0123456789  |     null     | 
| 2  |   1    | 1234567890  |     null     | 
| 3  |   1    |    null     |  test@gmail  | 
| 4  |   2    |    null     |  andy@yahoo  | 
| 5  |   2    |    null     |  andy@gmail  |
```

Expected Results

```
| id | userId | phoneNumber | emailAddress |
-------------------------------------------
| 1  |   1    | 0123456789  |     null     |
| 2  |   1    | 1234567890  |     null     |
| 5  |   2    |    null     |  andy@gmail  |
```

I wrote the query below and it returns the desired results, but I'm interested to see if there is a better, more optimal way to achieve this. Rather than writing multiple subqueries.

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
WHERE phoneNumber IS NOT NULL 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM A 
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) 
             FROM A WHERE phoneNumber IS NULL 
                AND userId NOT IN (SELECT userId 
                                   FROM A 
                                   WHERE phoneNumber IS NOT NULL) 
             GROUP BY userId)
```

Comment: Considering your code already achieves the desired result, this question may be more suitable for [**StackExchange's CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead :)

Comment: So: if for an ID there is at least one non-null phone number, you must return distinct non-null phone numbers? Meaning, for each distinct non-null phone number, just pick one row with that (id, phonenumber) (with whichever email address it happens to have)? And if for an id all the phone numbers are NULL, then just pick one row (ANY row) for that id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `COUNT()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT A.*,
         COUNT( phoneNumber) OVER ( PARTITION BY userId ) AS ct,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY id DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   A
)
WHERE  phoneNumber IS NOT NULL
OR     ( ct = 0 AND rn = 1 );
```